# Why do I get zeros in my List?

Tags: list, plot, octave

I don't understand why my list gets two zeros more than I need.

This is my code:

```
x=(0:0.01:12);
a=3;
y=cos(2*pi*2*x);
hold on
liste_A(1:1:72)=0;
for k=0:1:72
   for z=0:0.01:12
      vergleich = fix(100*k*1/6)/100;
      if(vergleich == z)
         liste_A(k+1)=z;
      end
   end
end
bla=(0:1/6:12)
stem(bla,liste_A)
```

Usually my list should continue with the value 0.83, but I reserve a zero. See this image:

[image]

Comment: So your initial question was answered by siehe-falz: Don't compare floating points for equality. Instead check if the difference is below some constraint (for example 10 * eps). But for your code: I hope you don't want to use this code to create a linear sequence, right?

Comment: My exercice is to simulate Aliasing. So i want to sample a cosinus function like a Analog digital converter and sinc- Interpolate it with my sample values . In my exercice i have the same problem. The 3. and 6th sample is 0

Comment: So i want to find a solution in this code and use a similar code for up and downsampling with the sinc function. But before i can downsample the function  i need a list of values and i decided to do it with diracs. So and how i can compare 2 floats? i tried different ways like fix, uint64... to avoid the precision effect but nothing helped... Now i try to check the differenc this is a nice idea ty

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a finite precision effect. If you run the modified code you will see that the two values you are comparing are not equal for the case k=5.

```
hold on
output_precision(18)
liste_A(1:1:72)=0;
for k=0:1:72
  for z=0:0.01:12
    vergleich = fix(100*k*1/6)/100;
    if (abs(vergleich-z)<1e-15)
      liste_A(k+1)=z;
      if (k==5)
        fix(100*k*1/6)/100
        z
      end
    end
  end
end
bla=(0:1/6:12)
stem(bla,liste_A)
```